# Erlang cryptography module - ECDSA, RSA, SHA256 and so on

Tags: hash, erlang, cryptography, openssl

I need a module that can generate keypairs, compute secure hashes and crypt and sign data. Is there any that module? Or maybe there is interface for OpenSSL crypto functions ?

Answer (score 1):

[sha2](http://steve.vinoski.net/code/sha2.erl) modile for sha256

Answer (score 1):

Read crypto module first. Now it's NIF since R14A so you can find out what sort of OpenSSL C  functions are used.

Comment: I don't find in documentation for crypto module (http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html - that doc?) any function that generates keypairs, SHA256 or ECDSA.

Comment: Not all functions you listed are in the documentation. But at least when you read the lib/crypto/c_src/crypto.c you can find out how they are implemented with OpenSSL APIs.